# Updating database from ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, insert-update

I've just started using mvc 4 and am having trouble updating my database. In my database I have a table called seats with two columns: seatnum and status. Below I am selecting the seats where the status matches the seat numbers contained in the seatss string(A1, A2 etc) I want to update the status to the value of the ID string but have no idea how to implement this.

```
public JsonResult Checkout(string seatss, string ID)
{
    var seats = from b in db.seats
                select b;

    seats = seats.Where(b => seats.Contains(b.seatnum));

    foreach(var seat in seats)
    {
        //Perform status update on seats(This is the bit I can't figure out)
        //$query="update seats set status='0' where seatnum="; (PDO query I want to implement)
    }

    return Json(seats, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // returns the selected seats as a json object.
}
```

Comment: I am also wondering if this should be refactored ` seats = seats.Where(b => seats.Contains(b.seatnum));` to use the `Any()` method

Comment: Yes, your LINQ query doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm completely new to using mvc 4 and ef so I have no clue

Answer (score 1):

As far as each entity is bound to the context (you are not using `AsNoTracking`) you can just update your values and save the context.

```
foreach(var seat in seats)
{
    seat.status = 0;
}

db.SaveContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from a related question I posted earlier.

```
foreach(var seat in seats)
{
    seat.status = int.Parse(ID);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming your using EF and not ADO.

```
seats.ForEach(x => x.Status = ID);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It's that easy.

Comment: Where did you find method `ForEach()`?

Comment: he probably assumed that this was utilizing `List<T>.foreach` since the linq query is not returning a `.ToList()` then that could be where his assumption went wrong.